# cannot run nightwatch.js tests in chrome browser on linux machine

Tags: linux, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I am trying to run nightwatch.js in chrome browser on linux machine.
My nightwatch tests run perfectly on windows machine using windows version of chrome driver.

I updated nightwatch.json file and gave path to linux version of chromedriver but my tests do not run and give error

npm run test-e2e --test tests/regression/testcase1.js

************Command Line Argument:*********************

Starting selenium server... started - PID:  12625

## [regression / TEST1] Test Suite

Running:  Login to UI

Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server

Error writing log file to: /home/abc/testing/AutomationFramework/logs/selenium-debug.log

Connection refused! Is selenium server started?
{ value:
   { message: 'Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService\nBuild info: version: \'3.12.0\', revision: \'7c6e0b3\', time: \'2018-05-08T15:15:08.936Z\'\nSystem info: host: \'virtualserver01\', ip: \'127.0.1.1\', os.name: \'Linux\', os.arch: \'amd64\', os.version: \'4.4.0-124-generic\', java.version: \'1.8.0_171\'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown',
     error: 'session not created' },
  status: 33 }

I also have Google chrome installed on my linux machine
$ google-chrome --version

Google Chrome 65.0.3325.181

My nightwatch.json file is as follows

```
   {

      "src_folders" : ["tests"],
      "output_folder" : "reports",
      "globals_path" : "nightwatch.global.js",
      "custom_commands_path": "./commands",


      "selenium" : {
        "start_process" : true,
        "server_path" : "./bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar",
        "log_path" : "./logs",
        "port" : 4444,
        "cli_args" : {
          "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "./bin/chromedriver"
        }
      },

      "test_settings" : {
        "default" : {
          "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
          "use_xpath": true,
          "selenium_port"  : 4444,
          "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
          "screenshots" :{
              "enabled" : true,
              "path" : "./screenshots",
              "on_failure" : true
          },
            "desiredCapabilities": {
            "browserName": "chrome",
            "javascriptEnabled": true,
            "acceptSslCerts": true,
            "chromeOptions": {
                "args": ["disable-web-security"],
                "prefs": {

                }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Update the question with the command you have used to start the _Selenium Server_

Comment: selenium server is set to start as true in nightwatch.json


"selenium" : {
        "start_process" : true,